# Static files are not loading in django1.11

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, static-files

I'm a newbie in django. I've been trying to develop a website with django1.11. But I got stuck at some point. The static files are not coming through the templates. Any help!

**settings.py**

```html
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'agr8w4(pcdz077#8n2ow1z8_@e-%6(evtw((-3g$&$_wf1&!@1'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'photo',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pro.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pro.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "our_static" ),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
    )

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_root")
```

**urls.py**

```html
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from photo.views import home
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
#urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterrens()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',home,name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
 return render(request,"home.html",{})
```

**home.html**

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

 <title>Photography</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/our_static/css/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Something here</h1>
 <h2>Anything!</h2>
 <section>
  <div>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
     <li><a href='#aboutus'>AboutUs</a></li>
     <li><a href='#portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href='#services'>Services</a></li>
     <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </section>
 <img src= "{% static '/our_static/img/a.jpg' %}" height="500" width="500"  >

 <footer>
  &copy;Copyrights@2017. All rights reserved.
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header, nav, footer {
 display: block;
}

body{
 text-align: center;
}

header{
 color: #777777;
}
```

Directory structure goes like this!

[image: folder structure]

`python manage.py collectstatic` works fine without any errors, and the files are copied to the static_root as well. But it didnt load on the page when runs `python manage.py runserver`
Here's what I got when run it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `our_static` from the url. It is not needed as the `static` tag replaces it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
<img src= "{% static 'img/a.jpg' %}" height="500" width="500"  >
```

Comment: @JoanKennedy glad I could help =)